# Var Password hiding JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a WEbsite for me and a friend, and we want to make the website more personal, so we put a chat on it. We also, didn't want the chat public so, we resorted to putting a password on the site suing JS. But, we've had issues with this, people are able to inspect element and see what the passwords are, and get into the site, and do whatever they wish. Is there any way to hide the passwords or the whole area of code, so no one else can get on the website? Here is the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--hide
var password;
var pass1="unknown1";
var pass2="unknown2";
password=prompt('Enter Password To View The Page',' ')
if (password == pass1|| password == pass2) {
alert('Correct password, Welcome.');
}
else{ 
window.location="http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should do it on the server side.

Comment: That's why client side authentication is never safe. You can't do anything there, clients have full control over their machine. You must do authentication where *you* have full control: the server.

Comment: That's [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)-- not nearly enough to actually be secure. Absolutely do it on the server side.

Comment: To some extent u can make it difficult by obfuscating ur JS. But finally server side is the only safe way.

Comment: Impossible to do on the client-side. You can either do it on the server side or use php (which is also server side)

Comment: Maybe not ENTIRELY impossible. I suppose you could try and hash the input client side, fetch something to compare against using Ajax and compare. Maybe not very secure, but it still could be possible to authenticate client side without having the password easily readable. However, other than for testing and fun, I would not suggest this or use it for anything serious.